# useCallback - prevent infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-loop, usecallback

I'm having a function object wrapped inside an `useCallback` statement which needs to invoke a function that is being injected via props:

```
const update = useCallback(() => {
    /*some stuff*/
    props.OnUpdate();
}, [..other_args, props.OnUpdate]);

useEffect(() => {
    update();
}, [args]);
```

Which leads to an infinite loop. If I remove `props.OnUpdate` from the dependencies array, the build is showing a warning that `OnUpdate` needs to be present in the dependencies array (or pass an empty array).

If I don't use `useCallback`, I end up with another warning: `The 'update' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line XY) change on every render. To fix this, wrap the definition of 'update' in its own useCallback() Hook`

**EDIT**
Here's the code of the `OnUpdate` which gets injected:

```
const callback = useCallback(() => {
    update({
        command: props.Command,
        target: props.Target
    });
}, [props.Command, props.Target, update])
```

Where `update` comes from a custom hook, which works correctly

Comment: Can you share the code for `OnUpdate`? You probably need to memoize it as well using `useCallback`, as it might result in `update` changing on every render.

Comment: What are `args` and `other_args`, and _some stuff_? Those are important to make this code reproducible.